# Hadoop Job - Using all the cores in my machine

Tags: optimization, hadoop, configuration, mapreduce

My hadoop job with default configurations -> Local mode on local file system was not using all the cores(16) in my system -> by using all cores I mean, I could see activity in all the cores at various instances.But, My CPU usage [from `top`] never went beyond 200%, hence I changed these configuration in my `conf`.

`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`  to set this to 8 and `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` to set this to 8 as well.

Still the usage of my cores stays less than 300%. How do I get the maximum throughput from machine by using all the cores ?

Also, I my files are in the size of ~1TB.This is the sample log from job run. I see that it creates multiple(temp) splits while running the job. This cycle of creating a split  and processing it continues(repeatedly). My hunch is that the during each cycle, it creates a temp file and merges them finally. Is there a way we could increase some buffer size to process bigger chunks (for my large input files) ?

```
13/12/01 12:58:10 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/12/01 12:58:10 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/12/01 12:58:10 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/12/01 12:58:10 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
13/12/01 12:58:10 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 16702718; bufvoid = 99614720
13/12/01 12:58:10 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 0; kvend = 262144; length = 327680
13/12/01 12:58:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
13/12/01 12:58:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
13/12/01 12:58:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 16702718; bufend = 33439467; bufvoid = 99614720
13/12/01 12:58:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 262144; kvend = 196607; length = 327680
13/12/01 12:58:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 1
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 2
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 3 sorted segments
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 3 segments left of total size: 36912217 bytes
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1988835396_0001_m_000543_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1988835396_0001_m_000543_0' done.
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1988835396_0001_m_000543_0
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1988835396_0001_m_000544_0
13/12/01 12:58:12 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@17aee8b0
```

Please to suggest other `tuning techniques` that I could follow to improve the process.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a Pseudo distribution, so your problem (at a guess) is that with so many process slots available to Hadoop, you're now limited by by disk IO - meaning that your Hard Disk (and again i'm assuming you only have a single HDD) can only read so much data in parallel - in this case your processes is said to be IO bound.

How can you use all your available CPU - well you could write a job that is not IO bound and for each input record performs some complex calculation (maybe some matrix multiplication, or the Pi Estimator example - but i'm not sure how CPU intensive that is).

Comment: seems like is nothing wrong with the configs/code.It is within the hardware that creates the bottleneck to slower the process?

Comment: The HDD has a specific bandwidth that it can read data off the disk. The CPU can transfer this data in, process it and write it out with a considerably higher bandwidth. With a single disk you also have contention between reading and writing the results (disk 'thrashing')

Comment: Didn't know the process had a term - thrashing . Learned it :) the http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/t/thrash.htm link suggests that increasing the RAM will solve the issue, I have a RAM of size 64GB, which is as high as it could get. Even then I face the problem. Can I change some config to ask Hadoop to use more RAM than it already does ?

Comment: It won't matter - your disk has a fixed bandwidth by which it can read  the data into memory. For example reading a 1TB file from 1 disk has a  theoretical time (depending on the disk), but reading the same 1TB file off 10 disks should in theory be 10x faster

Comment: so by theory - the only way to bypass is to have multiple disks. Would using a parallel file system with a single multicore processor help ?

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems to me that you are I/O bound. This simply means that your disks cannot provide enough data to keep all your cpus busy.

Essentially there's two ways to change this

1. You put more io capacity in your system. I.e. put more separate disks in and ensure that the input files are evenly spread over those disks.
2. Male your CPUs do more with the same data.

Comment: Is there a way (without adding additional hardware) to by-pass IO boundness and increase the throughput ? Maybe, read bigger chunks or something like that.Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The 'best' thing you can go for is to try to minimized the movements of the harddisk head. Aim for 'sequential' reads/writes. So less mappers / reducers may increase performance.

Comment: Ah, I see ! I was testing with default number of mappers/reducers(2 I guess) and then changed to the current 8M and 8R approach. For a file of size(5GB for testing),my runtime was reduced from 8 minutes to 3 minutes when using 8M/8R approach. Is there a number in-between these that could better the performance.

Comment: Where this optimum lies is specific to the job you are running. Essentially it has to do with the CPU cycles per 'Megabyte of Data' that you are trying to do.